# Stop second event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a multi-level menu, where the submenu is being displayed with jquery.
It drops down when a main link is hovered, then slides up when the mouse leaves.
I want to stop the mouseleave action, when mouseover is active, but i can't stop the second event (animate->margin-bottom). I'm new to jquery, so i went through many questions and googled a lot, but i don't really understand what i'm supposed to do here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
jQuery(".item-102 a").on('mouseenter', function() {
  jQuery("#horizontal-menu").animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, 300);
  jQuery("#submenu").slideDown("slow");
});
jQuery("#submenu").on('mouseleave',function() {
  jQuery("#submenu").delay(2000).slideUp("slow");
  jQuery("#horizontal-menu").delay(2000).animate({"margin-bottom": "+20px"}, 200);
});

jQuery("#submenu").on('mouseover', function() {
  jQuery(this).stop();
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be much appreciated

Comment: i'm developing this as part of a joomla template. i'm sorry but i can't provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Try binding to [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of `mouseover`...

Comment: Sorry, i've just updated the code. There's a mouseenter event, so it didn't work that way.

Comment: consider use of underscore.js method once()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
jQuery("#submenu").on('mouseover', function()
{
  jQuery(this).stop();
  jQuery("#horizontal-menu").stop();
});
```

Comment: It's partially working, thanks!
But when i swing over it with my mouse, it starts adding up that +20px margin-bottom, pixel by pixel. Can i delay that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it, thanks everyone. Hsz's answer was good, but it didn't fully stop the event, so here's the solution:

```
function(){
jQuery(".item-102 a").on('mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery("#horizontal-menu").animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, 300);
        jQuery("#submenu").slideDown("slow");
});

var hover_off = false;
jQuery("#submenu").mouseover(function (){
    hover_off = false;
});
jQuery("#submenu").mouseleave(function() {
    hover_off = true;
    setTimeout(myMouseOut, 1000);
});
function myMouseOut(){
    if (hover_off == true){
        jQuery("#submenu").delay(1000).slideUp("slow");
        jQuery("#horizontal-menu").delay(1000).animate({"margin-bottom": "+20px"}, 200);
    }
};
```